# To identify latest div pop-up out of many opened in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="one" style="display:none;"> </div>
<div id="two" style="display:none;"> </div>
<div id="three" style="display:none;"> </div>

$('#one').show();
$('#three').show();
$('#two').show();
```

All the the divs are shown. But how to identify $('#two') div is opened latest.
Kindly help.

Comment: what u want ???? u want to open particular click div ???

Comment: This can be done by a simple tricks, Declare an array, on click of each element push the value to the array. the last element will be the latest clicked div

Comment: @Raj what if the popups are not opened with click?

Comment: You tray to use array.....

Comment: element index can be pushed into the array on callback of show. trigger method may vary . But show will be called right. make sense??

Comment: Did my answer below help any @Megha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a variable named lastOpened and set its value each time you open a new div.

```
var lastOpened;

$('#one').show();
lastOpened = 'one';

$('#three').show();
lastOpened = 'three';

$('#two').show();
lastOpened = 'two';
```

Comment: Megha, it's considered polite to Mark as Answer if someone helps.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, every little bit helps.  :)